Can I use Swift Package Manager (SPM) and CocoaPods together in the same Capacitor application?
I have an already existing Capacitor app that is built using CocoaPods. All my plugins use CocoaPods and it works well.
However, I need to create a new custom Capacitor Plugin which requires a third party dependency that is only distributed via SPM. I have tried manually adding the dependency through xcode and adding the dependency to my Package.swift file but I keep getting the error: No such module ... whenever I build the iOS app.
Is it possible for Capacitor apps to use both SPM & CocoaPods? Or do I need to stick with one package manager when using Capacitor?
